# Find temperature range in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I search in Word to find ONLY the following pattern: 50 deg, 51 deg, 52 deg, … 59 deg?

By the way I want it to find deg and degrees, so I guess that means a string that starts with the pattern.

The closest I’ve gotten it `5? deg`, which finds what I want, but includes loads of extra hits. I can’t find a wildcard for a single numerical DIGIT.

I don’t see a way to find a string that has a wildcard in the middle of it, then `5? deg` would probably work well enough, but it’s not like I can put it in quotes.

By the way, what I’m doing is searching my diary to find the last time the temperature was in the 50s. I’m convinced 20 years ago Word search could do this and there was a “#” wildcard for a single digit, (plus a single alphabet charcter).

Answer (score 2):

#### I can’t find a wildcard for a single numerical DIGIT.

`[0-9]` looks for any single digit number

`[0-9]{1,2}` will match 1 or 2 digits

> How do I find 50 deg, 51 deg, 52 deg, … 59 deg?

Try `[5][0-9][ ][d][e][g]`

Further Reading: [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm#Theory1)

Comment: Thank you, your answer works and I learned a lot, but I SCREWED up big time the wording of my question. I meant how do you find Word documents on the computer from the Word Open dialog box with that pattern with ADVANCED QUERY SYNTAX. I'm going to rewrite and resubmit my question.